# Resolve error obtaining dependencies: Could not find artifact, Grails

Tags: grails, grails-plugin

I add plugin `compile 'org.grails.plugins:spring-security-core:3.1.1'` to my existing Grails 2.4.4 project. When I download source jar or refresh dependency from GGTS I got error as below.

```
Resolve error obtaining dependencies: Could not find artifact org.grails.plugins:spring-security-core:zip:3.1.1 in grailsCentral (https://repo.grails.org/grails/plugins) (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)
Error |
Resolve error obtaining dependencies: Could not find artifact org.grails.plugins:spring-security-core:zip:3.1.1 in grailsCentral (https://repo.grails.org/grails/plugins) (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)
Error |
```

I tried uncomment

```
 mavenRepo  "http://repository.codehaus.org"
 mavenRepo "http://download.java.net/maven/2/"
 mavenRepo "http://repository.jboss.com/maven2/"
```

and also tried

```
 mavenRepo "https://repo.grails.org/grails/core" or mavenRepo "http://repo.grails.org/grails/core"
```

I also tried solution given in some stackoverflow questions. But did not solve my error. Does anyone has solution?
My `BuildConfig.grovvy` is as below

```
grails.servlet.version = "3.0" // Change depending on target container compliance (2.5 or 3.0)
grails.project.class.dir = "target/classes"
grails.project.test.class.dir = "target/test-classes"
grails.project.test.reports.dir = "target/test-reports"
grails.project.work.dir = "target/work"
grails.project.target.level = 1.6
grails.project.source.level = 1.6
//grails.project.war.file = "target/${appName}-${appVersion}.war"

grails.project.fork = [
    // configure settings for compilation JVM, note that if you alter the Groovy version forked compilation is required
    //  compile: [maxMemory: 256, minMemory: 64, debug: false, maxPerm: 256, daemon:true],

    // configure settings for the test-app JVM, uses the daemon by default
    test: [maxMemory: 768, minMemory: 64, debug: false, maxPerm: 256, daemon:true],
    // configure settings for the run-app JVM
    run: [maxMemory: 768, minMemory: 64, debug: false, maxPerm: 256, forkReserve:false],
    // configure settings for the run-war JVM
    war: [maxMemory: 768, minMemory: 64, debug: false, maxPerm: 256, forkReserve:false],
    // configure settings for the Console UI JVM
    console: [maxMemory: 768, minMemory: 64, debug: false, maxPerm: 256]
]

grails.project.dependency.resolver = "maven" // or ivy
grails.project.dependency.resolution = {
    // inherit Grails' default dependencies
    inherits("global") {
        // specify dependency exclusions here; for example, uncomment this to disable ehcache:
        // excludes 'ehcache'
    }
    log "error" // log level of Ivy resolver, either 'error', 'warn', 'info', 'debug' or 'verbose'
    checksums true // Whether to verify checksums on resolve
    legacyResolve false // whether to do a secondary resolve on plugin installation, not advised and here for backwards compatibility

    repositories {
        inherits true // Whether to inherit repository definitions from plugins

        grailsPlugins()
        grailsHome()
        mavenLocal()
        grailsCentral()
        mavenCentral()
        // uncomment these (or add new ones) to enable remote dependency resolution from public Maven repositories
//        mavenRepo "http://repository.codehaus.org"
//        mavenRepo "http://download.java.net/maven/2/"
//        mavenRepo "http://repository.jboss.com/maven2/"


    }

    dependencies {
        // specify dependencies here under either 'build', 'compile', 'runtime', 'test' or 'provided' scopes e.g.
        // runtime 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.29'
        // runtime 'org.postgresql:postgresql:9.3-1101-jdbc41'
        test "org.grails:grails-datastore-test-support:1.0.2-grails-2.4"
    }

    plugins {
        // plugins for the build system only
        build ":tomcat:7.0.55"

        // plugins for the compile step
        compile ":scaffolding:2.1.2"
        compile ':cache:1.1.8'
        compile ":asset-pipeline:1.9.9"

        // plugins needed at runtime but not for compilation
        runtime ":hibernate4:4.3.6.1" // or ":hibernate:3.6.10.18"
        runtime ":database-migration:1.4.0"
        runtime ":jquery:1.11.1"

        // Uncomment these to enable additional asset-pipeline capabilities
        //compile ":sass-asset-pipeline:1.9.0"
        //compile ":less-asset-pipeline:1.10.0"
        //compile ":coffee-asset-pipeline:1.8.0"
        //compile ":handlebars-asset-pipeline:1.3.0.3"
        compile 'org.grails.plugins:spring-security-core:3.1.1'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Grails 2.x plugins each have a page in the 'plugin portal' at grails.org, and the page for this plugin is at http://grails.org/plugin/spring-security-core. As it says there, the latest version is 2.0.0, so you should add

```
compile ':spring-security-core:2.0.0'
```

in the plugins section of your BuildConfig.groovy.

Or if you *really* want to use version 3.1.1, upgrade your app to use Grails 3.x (this is left as an exercise for the reader) and add a dependency for v3.1.1 in the upgraded app's `build.gradle` file.

Grails 3 plugin pages are hosted in another section of the Grails site, and the page for the Grails 3 compatible spring-security-core plugin is at https://grails.org/plugins.html#plugin/spring-security-core

The 2.0.0 and 3.1.1 plugin docs are both available at https://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/

Comment: Even after adding both ` compile "org.grails.plugins:spring-security-core:2.0.0"` under dependencies and ` compile ':spring-security-core:2.0.0'` under plugins, I am still getting the error obtaining dependencies - ` Configuring classpath
| Error Resolve error obtaining dependencies: Could not find artifact org.grails.plugins:spring-security-core:jar:2.0.0 in grailsCentral (http://repo.grails.org/grails/plugins) (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)`

Answer (score 1):

It seems version 3.1.1 is hosted on bintray, which means you have the wrong repository.
https://bintray.com/grails/plugins/spring-security-core

But as the spring-security-core plugin maintains a 2.x branch on GitHub I guess version 2.0 is the latest supported version for Grails 2. So you might have to change your version, then the default repository should be good.

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced with this error. The plugin `spring-security-core-2.0.0` should be declared in `plugins` section of `BuildConfig.groovy`. And also, we don't need to precise the group id `org.grails.plugins`. Just like this:

```
plugins {
   // plugins for the build system only
   build ":tomcat:7.0.70" // or ":tomcat:8.0.22"
   compile":rest-client-builder:2.1.1"

   compile ":spring-security-core:2.0.0"
   ...
   ...
}
```